# How to delete certain values in a column after Boolean indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` as follows:

```
dates   values
2020-03-29 00:30:00 86.824
2020-03-29 00:45:00 86.923
2020-03-29 01:00:00 87.222
2020-03-29 01:15:00 87.52
2020-03-29 01:30:00 87.918
2020-03-29 01:45:00 88.415
2020-03-29 02:00:00 89.012
2020-03-29 02:15:00 89.807
2020-03-29 02:30:00 90.504
2020-03-29 02:45:00 90.702
2020-03-29 03:00:00 90.205
2020-03-29 03:15:00 88.713
2020-03-29 03:30:00 86.724
2020-03-29 03:45:00 84.636
2020-03-29 04:00:00 83.044
2020-03-29 04:15:00 82.249
```

I am considering Daylight saving and for that, I have to delete just the dates in the `dates` column and the values in the `values` column should not be deleted.

Since the daylight saving every year is on the last Sunday of march, I did the following to obtain the date of the last Sunday in march:

```
import datetime
currentYear = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
march_last_day = currentYear + '-03-31'
march_last_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(march_last_day, '%Y-%m-%d')

ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START = march_last_day - \
    datetime.timedelta((march_last_day.weekday() + 1) % 7)
ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START = ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START.replace(hour=2, minute=00)
ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START_2 = ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

values:

```
ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START.replace(hour=2, minute=00)
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 0)
ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 3, 0)
```

Now I want to delete the `dates` that lie between `ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START` (included) and `ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START_2` (excluded) from the `dates` column and the next values should be 'shifted' up, but the values in the `values` column shouldn't be disturbed.

I did:

```
mask = (df['dates'] >= ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START) & (df['dates'] < ZEIT_UMSTELLUNG_START_2)
df = df.loc[mask]
```

But it deletes both the columns.

**Desired output**

```
dates   values
2020-03-29 00:30:00 86.824
2020-03-29 00:45:00 86.923
2020-03-29 01:00:00 87.222
2020-03-29 01:15:00 87.52
2020-03-29 01:30:00 87.918
2020-03-29 01:45:00 88.415
2020-03-29 03:00:00 89.012
2020-03-29 03:15:00 89.807
2020-03-29 03:30:00 90.504
2020-03-29 03:45:00 90.702
2020-03-29 04:00:00 90.205
2020-03-29 04:15:00 88.713
         NaT        86.724
         NaT        84.636
         NaT        83.044
         NaT        82.249
```

If you compare my **desired output** with the original `df`, you can see that the timestamps between `02:00:00` and `03:00:00` have been deleted and the other columns have been just pushed or shifted up. After shifting, `NaN` in the last 4 rows of the `dates` column can be placed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df.loc[mask, 'dates'] = pd.NaT
df['dates'] = df['dates'].sort_values(ascending=True).tolist()
```

Comment: Hey, the solution partially works. The values in the `values` column are getting effected too.. I don't want them to move. Only the dates in the `dates` column have to be shifted up and in the end, 4 `NaTs` or `NaNs` must be placed

Comment: As you can see in the desired output I posted, the values in the `values` column are not being effected

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't the value corresponding to the date? Shifting only dates column will mess up the date value relation.

Comment: Yep, I am sure.

Comment: `df['dates'] = df['dates'].sort_values(ascending=True).values` This worked for me.